# RewriteRule directive redirect to unexisting page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have trouble setting directives in .htaccess file. Trying to achieve that if visitor tries to open

```
http://localhost/occasions/anniversary/
```

... it have to call browse.php file in root directory, and to send 'anniversary' as one of the parameters.

I defined directive like:

```
RewriteRule ^/occasions/(.*)/$ http://localhost/browse.php?page=$1
```

... but it returns Page not found error.

Can you tell me why, and help me to solve this.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your first slash in your RewriteRule, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^occasions/(.*)/$ http://localhost/browse.php?page=$1
```

It won't match when using RewriteRule within `.htaccess` files, as this first slash isn't passed for evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with Firefox + TamperData Addon and check the response to see where is the page redirecting instead of `browse.html`.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Comment: It isn't redirecting at all.  He's getting the 404 because the RewriteRule isn't being properly matched.